# Laravel 5.4 - Correct Validation rule for a required parameter that can be zero

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to validate a request to load stock into a table. Up until now stock has always had a positive value and the following validation rule worked exactly as expected:

```
[
    "value" => "required|integer|min:0"
]
```

Stock is stored and can have multiple values and *now* stock can have a `value` of zero (0), I don't think it works with the 'required' rule.

I have changed it to use 'present' which I thought should suffice however it still fails, and adding 'nullable' also doesn't work:

```
[
    "value" => "present|integer|min:0"
]
```

Are there validation rules to specify that a field must be present but the value can be zero?

Comment: Did you try regex validation? Something like `regex:[0-9]+`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was actually with my use of `$request->intersect(...)` in that it treats keys with a value of zero (0) as false and therefore removes them from the request data array.

For anyone else who may encounter this issue, here is the solution to treat zero (0) values as truthy while; null values, empty strings, and false will be treated as false.

*Nb*. `$params`, `$rules`, and `$messages` are `array`s. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#manually-creating-validators for more information.

```
return \Validator::make(array_filter($request->only($params), function($param) {
    // This is needed to strip out empty values but treat zero (0) as truthy (default array_filter behaviour is
    // to treat zero (0) as false) but we want these values to be present in the validated request data array as
    // zero (0) in the context of a denomination is valid now that we will hold unactivated stock in the Vault.
    return ($param !== null && $param !== false && $param !== '');
}), $rules, $messages);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your initial validation rule just keeps working as desired; `required` doesn't throw an error on `0`:

```
[
    "value" => "required|integer|min:0"
]
```

From the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-required):

> The field under validation must be present in the input data and not
>   empty. A field is considered "empty" if one of the following
>   conditions are true:
>
> - The value is null.
> - The value is an empty string.
> - The value is an empty array or empty Countable object.
> - The value is an uploaded file with no path.

Comment: The validator definitely fails and removes the value from the data array when the field is either required or present and the value is 0 (zero).

Comment: Then I'm afraid there must be something else going on. The validator really works this way.

Comment: Hi @Propaganistas I found the solution and posted it yesterday. Thanks for your help though.